# Make the location authorization for an application message appear at the first launch of the application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager

I want to show the message which asks the user if he accepts that the application will use the location services in his device. How can i implement that, WITHOUT saving his location? I've tried to do `startLocationUpdates` and then `stopLocationUpdates`, but that doesn't work. If i remove the `stopLocationUpdates`, that works, but the location indicator remains in the status bar.

If you ask why i need this, I'm using Core Location methods few screens later. Before using them, i check for `+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus` , and if it's different from "Authorized", i give an alert message. Is that wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you call to `startLocationUpdates` and then `stopLocationUpdates` in the same method?

If this is the case then try the following:

```
// Assuming that you have a property called locationManager
// If you don't then you should at least have an initiated member 
// in order to succeed with the second line below
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.locationManager performSelector:@selector(stopUpdatingLocation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

This way the `stopLocationUpdates` method will be called in the next runloop.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I've just had to change the delay to 0.2, because sometimes it worked and sometimes not.

Comment: Hey, will it be approved by apple?
A quote from apple guidelines:
"4.1 Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected"

Comment: The app will automatically prompt the user from the OS for permission to use location. You should be fine.

Comment: @BillBrasky, That's alert of "Location Authorization" is only available is only available on ios 4.2 and later, isn't it ?

Comment: No, the authorization should be there for all devices 4.0 and up.